# Alchemists Vial rules

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you use [Alchemist's vial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398640)'s ability as an instant, if you are able to pay the cost? For example, can it be used to prevent my creature from attacking, once i have declared it.

Answer (score 6):

You are able to activate it anytime you could cast an instant.

However once a creature has been declared an attacking or blocking creature the Vial's ability doesn't do anything, since it prevents a creature from being declared an attacker/blocker but doesn't undo that declaration.

From the Gatherer Rulings:

> Activating the last ability of Alchemist’s Vial targeting a creature that’s already attacking or blocking won’t cause that creature to stop attacking or blocking. It will prevent that creature from attacking or blocking in any additional combat phases the turn may have (although this is unusual).

Answer (score 0):

All activated abilities can be played anytime you could play an instant, unless the card specifically states otherwise.

Magic Comprehensive Rules:

> 112.3b Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]” **A player may activate such an ability whenever he or she has priority.**

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: That's a surprising downvote. What did I do wrong? Is it the lack of comprehensive rules excerpt? Or the old "played" term instead of the new "activated"?

Comment: I have included the relevant rule, but I'm leaving the wording unmodified. I consider it more accessible for the total newbies - the only group that might benefit from this question.

Comment: It might be because you don't answer the entire question, they also ask about removing attackers/blockers after they have been declared

Comment: @diego Ah, thank you.

Well, that other part was presented as an "example" of the same situation, and I have treated it as an (unfitting) example, not as another question.